# How do I change the automatic version number in bitkeeper?

Tags: version-control, bitkeeper

I have a personal bitkeeper repository and would like the version numbers to change from 1.xxx to 2.xxx.

My usage is a perl library and I have made major changes to the calling sequence and would like the SCCS strings that automatically get updated to reflect the new sequence. This way the use Module VERSION method will easily determine which calling sequence without having to specify 1.32 is the old one and 1.33 is the new one, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BitKeeper doesn't support changing the major number (or release number in SCCS lingo). Also note that coding logic that depends on revision numbers is fraught with peril as they can be unstable (e.g. what is revision 1.33 on your tree might be moved to revision 1.28.1.1 once you push).

Comment: That's exceptionally useful information. Thanks. Is there any automatically incrementing stable number that I could use?

Comment: Not really. You can get a partial order but BitKeeper being a distributed system there is no way that I know of to get a total order (the "automatically incrementing stable number" you mention) out of it. BitKeeper keys are stable though, and they sort, but as I said, you won't get a total order).